# How to build a magazine app for iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I have to develop an iOS magazine/newspaper application and I have an important question before starting. 
I have been researching about this kind of apps in the App Store and it seems that they all work with something similar to PDF files, but how do they do to embed videos? For example, in this app:

https://itunes.apple.com/es/app/orbyt-for-ipad/id407963919?mt=8

You can download a newspaper that it is similar to a PDF file but you can click into images to enlarge or into videos to play them.

Can anybody point me to the right direction in order to achieve this? I think by knowing the way to do this kind of files would be a solution to my question.

Thanks

Comment: I am in queue too.

Comment: You can use Aquafadas in oder to do that. It allows you to create content and then embed it in an iOS app. It's used to create magasines and catalogs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use rich content in Book, I would suggest to use [ePub](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EPUB) instead of pdf. ePub stores html internally for pages of book, and with html you have unlimited possibility - including vide, Audio, Image gallery, links etc. download sample ePub and replace extension with .zip . After extracting it, you will able to see html files.

For testing purpose, you can create ePub from pages [get more detail here](https://support.apple.com/en-in/HT202066) later, you can easily create web app with Php for creating ePub using html files.

There are open source ePub parser available on [github](https://github.com/ricobeck/KFEpubKit). You can get basic idea from there. At the end, It will display `html` in `uiwebview`.